# php/mysql - i am doing a web app that has 'achievements' (a bit like xbox achievements) - whats the best way to program this?

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller

i am going to have achievements such as

get 1000 points

login 20 times

complete 2 tasks within 24 hrs

etc

what is the best way to program this? (like, the logic behind it. it would be a wast eof reseouces to check every possible achievement on every page load)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fairly open-ended question. One approach is to store progress for what users have already achieved in a database table (one column for each achievement) and every time progress is made, up the progress value. A magic value for each achievement (null, 1 million, whatever) can be set when the target is reached and then you just need to check which columns in each user's entry have the magic value.

You could just store the progress and calculate the achievement status on each access, but I think that would be problematic for things like the time-limited tasks you mention and people might get irked if you change the goals for any reason and they lose achievements they had previously gained.

An arguably more correct approach would be to have a static "Achievements" table in which each row details one achievement, along with the goals. You'd then have a separate "Progress" table in which each user would have a row for every different achievement they are working towards. This is more work to implement, but will allow you to add / remove / alter goals much more easily at a later date than hard-coding them to column names in your progress table. I don't think you should underestimate the value this will give you later on. This way, the progress table can have multiple columns for each user / achievement combination, which allows you to store things like time achievement reached etc. and you can very simply get a list of achievements like this:

```
SELECT achievement_id
FROM   progress
WHERE  user_id = $user
AND    achievment_time IS NOT NULL
```

You've got to check *something* for each page load if you want to display achievements on each page, but if you record progress in one of these ways, you're not going back to first principles and calculating how many logins have been made, how many tasks have been completed, etc. every time - just a SELECT from your DB, which I assume is what you mean.

Recording progress is simple for things like number of logins (just increment a counter each time they perform the action), but you'll obviously have to think a bit more carefully about the logic for keeping tabs on progress for time-limited achievements. Here, you'll need to keep track of timestamps for when actions were performed in a separate table (you may already be doing this, of course) and each time a new timestamp is created, count those in the preceding time period to see if the achievement has been reached.